# Molecule with reversible exothermic conformational change?

Tags: conformers, chemistry-in-fiction, structural-biology

I proposed some exotic biochemistry on the Worldbuilding stack.
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/166814/digestive-system-of-the-ultimate-omnivore/166829#166829

> Your creature oxidizes molecules in its "stomach" which is more of a
>   furnace. Anything that can be oxidized is fair game - any reduced
>   carbon, or nitrogen, or metal salt. Oxidation produces heat. The
>   amount of heat produced is controlled by controlling oxygen ingress to
>   the stomach.
>
> Under hot conditions, certain metalloproteins change configuration.
>   The circulation brings these proteins into hot conditions near the
>   stomach and they capture heat energy with the configuration change.
>   When the hot-configured metalloprotein circulates out to the cold
>   exterior (possibly radiator plates or fins) it shifts back to the cold
>   configuration. This conformational shift is linked to an ATPase and
>   generates ATP for the creature to use for its muscles and metabolic
>   processes, as Earth life does.

I was challenged to produce a molecule which could capture and release energy in this way. Molecules do this all the time with a phase change - that is a steam engine. But is there any example of a molecule (or a whole type, perhaps) which undergoes a conformational change with heat that it later discharges in a controlled manner, with an exothermic relaxation back to the cold conformation. Not necessarily a biomolecule.

Comment: Thing is, they do it all the time! Every single compound with a conformer higher in energy would count.

Comment: @Mithoron - that sounds promising.  Can you lay out some examples in an answer?

Comment: No, that means, the topic is too broad and question probably on the way to get closed.

Comment: @Mithoron - it looks like you are right.  On the WB stack I was challenged that no molecule could do this and here on chemistry stack so many molecules can do it that it is not a question worth answering.  Woe!

Comment: :D Well, to be actually able to give off energy surplus to ATPase, the molecule should actually do not lose it - stay in "excited" conformation and only get isomerised by an enzyme and get its energy harvested. Now, that's not really common, *and* may be just rare enough!

Comment: Microscopic reversibility of the endothermic reaction makes it really hard to prevent the reverse happening without the ATP synthesis. What about using a known ion-driven ATP synthase with a molecule that binds ions when cold and releases them when hot to maintain the ion gradient?

Comment: @Andrew - I like it.  Can you propose one?